# sort with operator overriding does not get I want

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, functor

I am trying to sort a person vector by person.name and age. Therefore, I tried to override the `operator<` in the `Person` definition, and to use functor with `std::sort()`.

However, I did not get what I want. My expectation is that Persons are first ordered by their name, and then by their age. But I get the same result with both solutions:

```
che is less than xu
(wu, 30)
(che, 34)
(xu, 21)
```

What I expect order is:

```
(che, 34)
(wu, 30)
(xu, 21)
```

Could anyone help point the mistake I made? Thanks

The source code is:

```
class Person{
 public:
  string _name;
  int _age;

 public:
  Person(string name, int age):_name(name),_age(age){
  }
    bool operator<(const Person* b) const {
   cout<<"Expect "<<_name <<b->_name <<"   "<< (_name < b->_name)<<endl;
  if(_name != b->_name) {
      return _name < b->_name;
   }
    else return _age<b->_age;
   }

   bool operator<(const Person& b) const {
     if(_name!=b._name) {
       cout<<_name <<" is less than "<<b._name<<endl;
       return _name<b._name;
     }  else return _age<b._age;
   }
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Person& b) {
    out << "(" << b._name << ", " << b._age << ")"<<endl;
    return out;
}

};

bool PersonCompare(const Person* a, const Person* b ){
     cout<<"Expect "<<a->_name <<b->_name <<"   "<< (a->_name < b->_name)<<endl;
    if(a->_name != b->_name) {
      return a->_name < b->_name;
    }
    else return a->_age<b->_age;
}

class PersonPrint{
 public:
  PersonPrint(){
  }

  void operator()(const Person& person){
    cout<<person;
  }
 void operator()(const Person* person){
    cout<<*person;
  }
};




void testSort(){
  vector<Person*> personsList;
  personsList.push_back(new Person("xu", 12));
  personsList.push_back(new Person("che", 23));
  personsList.push_back(new Person("sxy", 34));
  /*std::sort(personsList.begin(), personsList.end(), [](Person* a, Person* b ){
      if(a->_name!=b->_name) return a->_name<b->_name;
      else return a->_age<b->_age;
      }); *///This works
 /* std::sort(personsList.begin(), personsList.end(), PersonCompare ) *///This works..
  std::sort(personsList.begin(), personsList.end()); //This does not work

  for_each(personsList.begin(), personsList.end(), PersonPrint());
}
```

==============
It is the logic error inside of lambda/operator. After changing `if(a._name<b._name)` to `if(a._name!=b._name)`, the error is fixed.

/////////////////////////////////////

I updated the code. 
Add `bool operator<(const Person* b) const{}` for class `Person`, and then try to sort a vector of `Person*`. But the result is not sorted as I expected, and the newly added `operator<(const Person*)` is not called. Any suggestion here? Thanks

Comment: Your mistake is not using your debugger to step through your code, one line at a time, and examining the values of all your variables and inspecting the logic of the executing code. This problem can be trivially identified using a debugger, and knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ devleoper.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, the issue is really an elementary logic error. Yeah a debugger would be nice, but it's not needed.

Comment: You are ordering by age anytime the first name is not less than the second - including when it is bigger.  Change the operator< to `if(name==b.name) return age<b.age; return name<b.name;` so that you only sort by age when the names are the same.

Comment: Ideally, change it to `std::tie(a.name, a.age) < std::tie(b.name, b.age)`, which does everything @Jerry said above but saves you all the boilerplate.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that the OP has ever heard of `std::tie`, and the current goal here is to not learn advanced templates and arcane reference-based logic; but rather implement a simple algorithm.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, `std::tie` isn't complicated, nor is it an "advanced template technique", and the issue is a rudimentary logic error. I like to solve logic errors before stepping into a debugger, if possible, because it saves me typically hours later. Using `std::tie` reduces the boilerplate to 1 line, and does it efficiently with modern C++ with no knowledge of template-metaprogramming required.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  I agree that the OP may not want to know about std::tie - I think Alexander was suggesting it to me and not the the OP.  Personally I think it is quite clever...

Comment: Thanks all. I made a change on the code and add another ques at the end of post. Is it the right way to override `bool operator<(const Person*) const` for `Person`, so that the vector of `Person*` can be sorted?  But it looks it is `operator<(const Person&)`, instead of thenew `operator<(Person*)` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparison function is treading the territories of undefined behavior. No surprise you are not seeing what you expect. 
From [std::sort's documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

> comp  -   comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the
>   **requirements of Compare**) which returns ​true if the first argument is
>   less than (i.e. is ordered before) the second.

Requirements of [Compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare):

> The return value of the function call operation applied to an object
>   of type Compare, when contextually converted to bool, yields true if
>   the first argument of the call appears before the second in the **strict
>   weak ordering relation** induced by this Compare type, and false
>   otherwise.

Your comparison function doesn't meet the criteria of strict week ordering.

You can simply do:

```
std::sort(persons.begin(), persons.end(), 
[](const Person& a, const Person& b) { return std::tie(a.name, a.age) < std::tie(b.name, b.age); })
```

I have written an article on this: https://isocpp.org/blog/2016/05/strict-weak-ordering-and-stl which you may want to refer.

Edit(Based on OP's edit):

This doesn't works because you have provided member functions for `Person` class whereas the type on which you want to call is `Person*`. Both are different types.
You will have to move the `PrintPerson` function's **definition** outside the class and make it **declare as a friend method** in Person class. Unfortunately you cannot do the same with the `bool operator<(Person *a, Person *b)` because operator overloading doesn't works with pointer types. Your only alternative is to pass a comparer.

Comment: Thanks. I update my post at the end with another similar question. Is it right way to override `bool operator<(const Person*) const{}` for `Person`, so that it can support sort for a vector of `Person*`?

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the "operator overloading doesn't works with pointer  types", do you mean this only refers to `operator<(const Person*)`.  In the test, the `operator<(const Person*)` in `Person` does not work, but I found the `operator()(const Person*)` inside of `PrintPerson` works, as it can print out all elements in `vector<Person*>`

Comment: the criteria for operator overloading is that atleast one of the parameters should be a class or enum type **if the function is at a namespace level**. Operator overloading still works with pointer types for member functions.